# Ошибка при обновлении Android SDK 29

Tags: unity3d, android-sdk, сборка

В Google Play при загрузке apk файла пишет:

> Измените целевой уровень Api 28 на 29

захожу в Unity -> в `player settings` -> меняю галочки на `API 29`.

При сборке проекта выдает сообщение на экране:

> Обновить Android SDK 29?

нажимаю обновить, затем получаю ошибку:

> Попробуйте установить вручную, прописав путь к `sdkmanager.bat`

прописываю путь в командной строке:

```
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.1.2f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\bin>sdkmanager.bat "platforms;android-29"
```

Потом соглашаюсь с лицензией.

И дальше выходит вот такая ошибка:

```
Accept? (y/N): y
Warning: Failed to read or create install properties file.
[===                                    ] 10% Installing Android SDK Platform 29
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.1.2f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\bin>
```

Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой - помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: 0


Проблема решена! запустил тот же путь в командной строке но от администратора. И все обновилось!

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена! запустил тот же путь в командной строке но от администратора. И все обновилось!